# Is there a way to purge FontAwesome with Webpack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, font-awesome

my project is currently using `Rails 6.1`, `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free 5.15.3` & Heroku. My config is straightforward:

```js
// package.json
{
  "name": "web",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    ...
  },
  ...
}

// app/javascript/packs/application.js
...
Rails.start()
...
import "stylesheets/application"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all"
```

I use FontAwesome icons as CSS classes, which I call within my `.html.erb` files:

```html
<i class="fas fa-users"></i>
```

I use very few icons from the framework (< 20), yet Webpack seems to compile the whole framework. Everything works fine, I am just surprised how the FA framework is still compiled in *all* possible formats (css (the only one I need), svg, webfonts).

Here are my Heroku build logs:

```
       Version: webpack 4.46.0
       Time: 19571ms
       Built at: 07/21/2021 9:10:54 PM

                                               Asset       Size  Chunks                                Chunk Names
                        css/application-e87f29dc.css   72.8 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]         application
                     css/application-e87f29dc.css.br   13.7 KiB          [emitted]                     
                     css/application-e87f29dc.css.gz   16.4 KiB          [emitted]                     
              js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js    128 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]         application
           js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js.br   25.4 KiB          [emitted]                     
           js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js.gz   29.3 KiB          [emitted]                     
          js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js.map    370 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]               application
       js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js.map.br   75.2 KiB          [emitted]                     
       js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js.map.gz   86.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
                                       manifest.json   1.82 KiB          [emitted]                     
                                    manifest.json.br  348 bytes          [emitted]                     
                                    manifest.json.gz  403 bytes          [emitted]                     
           media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-216edb96.svg    730 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
        media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-216edb96.svg.br    218 KiB          [emitted]                     
        media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-216edb96.svg.gz    249 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
          media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-329a95a9.woff   87.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
           media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-89a52ae1.eot    131 KiB          [emitted]                     
        media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-89a52ae1.eot.br   81.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
        media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-89a52ae1.eot.gz   88.6 KiB          [emitted]                     
           media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-9e138496.ttf    131 KiB          [emitted]                     
        media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-9e138496.ttf.br   81.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
        media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-9e138496.ttf.gz   88.5 KiB          [emitted]                     
         media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-c1210e5e.woff2     75 KiB          [emitted]                     
          media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-1017bce8.ttf   32.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
       media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-1017bce8.ttf.br     15 KiB          [emitted]                     
       media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-1017bce8.ttf.gz   15.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
          media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-19e27d34.svg    141 KiB          [emitted]                     
       media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-19e27d34.svg.br   30.3 KiB          [emitted]                     
       media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-19e27d34.svg.gz   36.3 KiB          [emitted]                     
         media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-36722648.woff   15.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
          media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-4079ae2d.eot   33.2 KiB          [emitted]                     
       media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-4079ae2d.eot.br   15.1 KiB          [emitted]                     
       media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-4079ae2d.eot.gz   15.9 KiB          [emitted]                     
        media/webfonts/fa-regular-400-68c5af1f.woff2     13 KiB          [emitted]                     
            media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-07c3313b.ttf    198 KiB          [emitted]                     
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-07c3313b.ttf.br   90.3 KiB          [emitted]                     
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-07c3313b.ttf.gz    100 KiB          [emitted]                     
            media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-13de59f1.svg    897 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-13de59f1.svg.br    199 KiB          [emitted]                     
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-13de59f1.svg.gz    250 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
          media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-ada6e6df.woff2   76.4 KiB          [emitted]                     
           media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-c6ec0800.woff   99.3 KiB          [emitted]                     
            media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-efbd5d20.eot    198 KiB          [emitted]                     
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-efbd5d20.eot.br   90.4 KiB          [emitted]                     
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-efbd5d20.eot.gz    100 KiB          [emitted]                     
       Entrypoint application = css/application-e87f29dc.css js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js js/application-5ac2d3a4589f0bac8765.js.map
        [0] ./node_modules/stimulus/index.js + 38 modules 77.4 KiB {0} [built]
            |    39 modules
        [2] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
        [5] ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 39 bytes {0} [built]
        [7] ./app/javascript/controllers sync _controller\.js$ 243 bytes {0} [built]
        [8] ./app/javascript/controllers/forecasts_controller.js 3.28 KiB {0} [optional] [built]
        [9] ./app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js 2.67 KiB {0} [optional] [built]
       [10] ./app/javascript/controllers/search_controller.js 4.37 KiB {0} [optional] [built]
       [11] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js + 4 modules 16.7 KiB {0} [built]
            | ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 585 bytes [built]
            | ./app/javascript/controllers/index.js 742 bytes [built]
            |     + 3 hidden modules
           + 6 hidden modules
       
       WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
       This can impact web performance.
       Assets: 
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-13de59f1.svg (897 KiB)
         media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-216edb96.svg (730 KiB)
         media/webfonts/fa-solid-900-13de59f1.svg.gz (250 KiB)
         media/webfonts/fa-brands-400-216edb96.svg.gz (249 KiB)
       
       WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
       You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
       For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
       Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--5-2!node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css:
           Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
              18 modules
       Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--6-2!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss:
           Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
           [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 43.7 KiB {0} [built]
               + 1 hidden module
       
       Asset precompilation completed (58.34s)
```

Should I worry about the size of these files like Webpack warns me? Is there any way to purge FontAwesome (like I do with Tailwind) so that only the used icons are compiled? Am I missing something about how Webpack works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could import only icons you wanna use

```js
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {
  faFacebookSquare,
  faGooglePlusSquare
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

library.add(faFacebookSquare, faGooglePlusSquare);
```

Note that if those icons do not show, then you maybe need dom helper

```js
import { library, dom } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {
  faFacebookSquare,
  faGooglePlusSquare
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
library.add(faFacebookSquare, faGooglePlusSquare);

// Kicks off the process of finding <i> tags and replacing with <svg>
dom.watch();
```

Comment: In my `node_modules`, I only have `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` and as I mentioned I import FontAwesome as CSS, not JS. Also, notice that my import only concerns the `/css` folder, yet, all kinds of webfonts are still compiled.